# "Flutter, Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1" what could be the issue?

Tags: flutter

When I tried to run the flutter application through `"Run without debugging"` or `"With debugging"` in `VS CODE` the application does not show up in the emulator (emulator is up and running). `Android studio` is properly installed. SDK path is updated in `env. variables`. Updated packages with `yaml` file. restarted `VSCODE`, restarted the computer, Problem still persists. What could be the issue?

**Debug console**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\flutter2.3\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\flutter2.3\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**Then I tried to upgrade yaml file packages with
flutter pub upgrade**

```
Resolving dependencies...
  async 2.8.1 (2.8.2 available)
  boolean_selector 2.1.0
  characters 1.1.0 (1.2.0 available)
  charcode 1.3.1
  clock 1.1.0
  collection 1.15.0
  cupertino_icons 1.0.3
  fake_async 1.2.0
  flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  flutter_svg 0.23.0+1
  flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  matcher 0.12.10 (0.12.11 available)
  meta 1.7.0
  path 1.8.0
  path_drawing 0.5.1+1
  path_parsing 0.2.1
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar 4.0.2
  petitparser 4.4.0
  sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
  source_span 1.8.1
  stack_trace 1.10.0
  stream_channel 2.1.0
  string_scanner 1.1.0
  term_glyph 1.2.0
  test_api 0.4.2 (0.4.6 available)
  typed_data 1.3.0
  vector_math 2.1.0 (2.1.1 available)
  xml 5.3.1
No dependencies changed.
5 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
```

**Then ran flutter pub outdated**

```
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name  Current   Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest   

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
characters    *1.1.0    *1.1.0      *1.1.0      1.2.0
vector_math   *2.1.0    *2.1.0      *2.1.0      2.1.1

transitive dev_dependencies:
async         *2.8.1    *2.8.1      *2.8.1      2.8.2
matcher       *0.12.10  *0.12.10    *0.12.10    0.12.11
test_api      *0.4.2    *0.4.2      *0.4.2      0.4.6
all dependencies are up-to-date.
```

Comment: Did you try flutter clean?

Comment: @KaushikChandru
It gives the error. `Deleting build... 7ms
Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.` But I'm the admin for my computer and I have admin privileges.

Comment: You may have admin privileges but flutter command would not have read or write permission to certain folders. Please change your sdk directory to a normal path.

Comment: @KaushikChandru changed it, placed flutter directory and updated env. variables, even moved project files, but it does not work properly, I changed my computer instead, I'm deleting this question as it attracts no more answers. thanks a lot btw :)